# How to validate select option for a Materialize dropdown?

Tags: html, materialize

I've got a basic select box using materializecss.

```
<select id="type" name="type" required="required" class="validate">
    <option value="" disabled="true" selected="selected">Choose your option</option>
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="tech">Tech</option>
    <option value="person">Personnel</option>
    <option value="resource">Resourcing</option>
</select>
<label data-error="Select an option">Type of Question</label>
```

I want the user to select an option before being able to submit the form.

How can I get it to display the `data-error` for the label if user doesn't select an option?

Answer (score 12):

```
$("select[required]").css({display: "block", height: 0, padding: 0, width: 0, position: 'absolute'});
```

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: You can add left: 50% so the warning text appears right in the middle of the select field.

Answer (score 9):

I faced similar problem. I little search I found an easy solution:

**Step 1:**

`material_select` makes your select hidden (`display: none`). And As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244754/materialize-css-select-list-validation#30566034), jQuery validator ignores hidden fields. So as a mentioned workaround, add following before validate method:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
       ignore: []
});

$("#yourForm").validate({
        errorClass: "invalid form-error",       
        errorElement : 'div',       
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent() );
        }
});
```

Also note that `form-error` class is custom class in my css:

```
.form-error{color: #D8000C;}
```

**Step 2:**

Make your select required, which is already applied in this question's `select` tag. Alternatively you can add your select marking as `required: true` in rules of `validate` method. But this is not necessary, if you have added `required` in your html select tag then that is fine.

That's it. With this, when a form is submitted or `$("#yourForm").valid()` is called, it will validate your select.

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking on a previous answer, I found adding the visibility hidden attribute helped clean things up

```
  $("select[required]").css({
    display: "block", 
    position: 'absolute',
    visibility: 'hidden'
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would be helpful:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    $(".error_note").remove();
    var select = $(this).find('select').filter("[required=required]");
    $.each(select , function(index, elm){
        val = $(this).val();    
        target = $(this).closest('.input-field');
        if (typeof target !== "undefined") {
            input_target = target.find('input.select-dropdown');
            if (typeof input_target !== "undefined") {                  
                if(val == '' || val == false || val == 0 || val == null){

                    input_target.css({'border-color':'#EA454B','box-shadow':'0 1px 0 0 #EA454B'});
                    input_target.after('<span class="error_note" style="color: #EA454B;font-size: 12px;">Please select this field.</span>');

                    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("body").offset().top},'slow' );
                    e.preventDefault();

                }else{
                    input_target.css({'border-color':'#9e9e9e'});
                }

            }
        }           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select[required]").css({display: "inline", height: 0, padding: 0, width: 0});
```

Answer (score 1):

hemu's answer helped me along with some discussions on the materialize forum. I came up with this solution which integrates nicely. The trick was to position the error label properly and give it it's color:

```
.select-wrapper label.invalid {
    margin-top: 62px;
    margin-left: -11px;
    color: #F44336;
}
```

You can find this and some more error placement trickery in the below Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b8frk03m/6/

Answer (score 1):

this worked better for me and JavaScript was not neccesary, just some simple CSS:

```
select[required]:focus{
    outline: none !important;
}

select[required]{
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Definitive Solution**

The problem is actually with the rendered `input` that replaces the `select` element. It is irrelevant that this select is hidden or not. The Materialize CSS engine does not verify if your select element is required or has the `validate` class. I don't know why they didn't put that code I will show you below, but that will solve the problem if you put it in a JavaScript file in your page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip(); // dica que aparece quando o usuário põe o mouse em cima do componente
    $('select').formSelect(); // montagem de campos <select> com material design
    // isto corrige o problema de renderização em campos select que exigem validação quando o campo é de preenchimento obrigatório
    const _requiredSelects = $("select[required].validate");
    _requiredSelects.parent().find('input').addClass('validate').attr('required', true)
    .keydown(function($event) { 
        return $event.keyCode == 9;
    });
    _requiredSelects.change(function($event) { 
        const _select = $event.target;
        const _value = $(_select).val();
        const _input = $(_select).parent().find('input');
        _input.removeAttr('readonly', '');
        _input.val(_select.options[_select.options.selectedIndex].label);
        if (_value != '') {
            _input.addClass('valid');
            _input.removeClass('invalid');
        } else {
            _input.addClass('invalid');
            _input.removeClass('valid');
        }
    });
    _requiredSelects.each(function(){
        const _this = $(this);
        const _helper = _this.parent().parent().find('.helper-text');
        if (_helper !== undefined) {
            const _input = _this.parent().find('input');
            _helper.insertAfter(_input);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```