# materialize css validate class not applying or not working for select dropdown

Tags: materialize

[image]

below is my materialize HTML code, Coi

```
<select name="designation_id" id="designation_id" class="validate ">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244754/materialize-css-select-list-validation) will help you for select box validation in material

Comment: Are you looking for validation or for it to be "required". The red line indicates to me that you have required on those fields...I believe you need both.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add required to the field along with the class validate.