# How do I initialize <select> using MaterializeCSS and AngularJS combined?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, materialize

I've been trying to add a simple **< select >** snippet to my page, but as I discovered [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258106/materialize-css-select-doesnt-seem-to-render), **MaterializeCSS starts off by disabling it**, and then re-enables (I'm assuming) once the correct jQuery plugin has been loaded (using directives, as shown [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angular-js))

I have not been able to find a good example on how to do this using AngularJS, and I would like to avoid moving to an angular-designed fork of Materialize if possible.

Here's what I got.

```
<label>
    test
    <select material-select>
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

I am planning to make a directive that initializes the **< select >**, then I'll use ng-repeat to populate it afterwards.

```
navApp.directive('myDropDown', function() {
    return {
        //This code is broken, I am not quite sure what I'm doing.
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).'select'.material_select();
        }
    };
});
```

I consider myself a novice at ASP.NET MVC, Entity Frameworks (using MySQL) and AngularJS, which are all the frameworks I'm currently using.

I also found [this resource on creating directives](https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/), but I am not sure how to adapt it to my situation.

I'd be deeply grateful for any help on this.

Comment: If you're using Angular, you should consider the official [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/).  Instead of jQuery plugins, it uses native directives.

Comment: @jme11 Thanks for the recommendation. Although Angular Material seems vastly incomplete, since I have no deadline I will start using it instead. If you had made an answer I would have marked it, but I'll give it to Michael for now.

Comment: @Michael's answer is correct and on point given your question, so I think it should have been the selected answer.  That said, I'm glad that you found my recommendation to look at a native approach helpful as well.  Best of luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MaterializeCSS multiple select not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700603/materializecss-multiple-select-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $(element).'select'.material_select();

What should be the result of this statement? The `.'select'` is no JS syntax.

try:

```
$(element).material_select(); // if the element is already the select element
```

or:

```
$(element).find('select').material_select(); // find a child select of the element
```

Comment: I decided to go with Angular Material (ng-material). Thank you for posting this though!