# MaterializeCSS multiple select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm having trouble getting the Materialize CSS multiple select box to work.

I know about the javascript function `material_select` that needs to be called.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kdo8ndb/1/)

[Documentation](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select)

Any help appriciated, perhaps I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you included the script/stylesheet?

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Working:
https://jsfiddle.net/8kdo8ndb/3/

Comment: That's odd, I added the js and css file in de external links section: http://prntscr.com/92eztj

Comment: If I remove the CSS ref from the external links it doesn't work, and when I remove the JS from the external links it does work, that's kinda odd.

Answer (score 0):

Include following tag under `<head>` tag -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

If you dont not waht to use CDN, You have make structure of files like -

```
MyWebsite/
  |--css/
  |  |--materialize.css
  |
  |--font/
  |  |--material-design-icons/
  |  |--roboto/
  |
  |--js/
  |  |--materialize.js
  |
  |--index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's kinda unrelated. Apparently the way the JS was loaded into the JSFiddle appears to be the problem. I used the external links section.