# Select not rendering in Materialize CSS and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS for my Angular application and for some reason, the `<select>` element fails to render (nothing visible; though when I right click to inspect element, I can see the `<select>` right there). However, when I apply `class = "browser-default"` to it, it starts working. As in a previous answer, I have also included

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

after loading all js files. Yet, it doesn't seem to work. Any idea what the possible issue can be?

Edit: Here's the related documnetation: http://materializecss.com/forms.html

Comment: Getting any console error ?

Comment: @Vineet nope, seems to me like a CSS issue than a JS one

Answer (score 1):

As in the answer found in: [Materialize CSS - Select Doesn't Seem to Render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258106/materialize-css-select-doesnt-seem-to-render)

You have to initialize the select using the JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Select - Single
    $('select:not([multiple])').material_select();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$('select').material_select();` after angular to load your select, for example:

you have a select like this:

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select ng-model="year" ng-options="year for year in years">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a year</option>
    </select>
    <label>Year</label>
</div>
```

When you are loading the list of years in your controller, you must use `setTimeout` to delay execution of the method `$('select').material_select()`. See below:

```js
function generateYears() {
    var years = [];
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    for (var year = currentYear; year >= 1900; year--) {
        years.push(year);
    }

    $scope.years = years;

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('select').material_select();
    }, 200);
}
```

With this the materialize select will work