# Materialize CSS select shows cut off

Tags: css, materialize

I have some code using Materialize CSS. I want to show a select with 15 options, but when I select it is cut off. The code in the container is inside a main tag.

[image]

```js
       $('select').material_select();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
     <select>
       <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Choose your option</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Option 3</option>
       <option value="4">Option 4</option>
       <option value="5">Option 5</option>
     </select>
     <label>Browser Select</label>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258106/materialize-css-select-doesnt-seem-to-render/28259097#28259097